# Google cloud healthcare export fails with error code 7

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, hl7-fhir, google-healthcare-api

Google cloud healthcare export fails with error code 7.  I'm exporting to GCS.
Some objects are created in GCS.
I see nothing appear, not even any kind of error, when I look in the related logs.
The command I run is like:

```
gcloud healthcare fhir-stores export gcs <fhir store id> --project=<project> 
--dataset=<dataset> --location=<location> --gcs-uri=gs://<bucket>/<folder>
```

The result I get is:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.healthcare.fhir-stores.export.gcs) {
  "code": 7,
  "message": "Operation execution failed."
}
```

When I look up the details with 'gcloud healthcare operations describe', I get this:

```
done: true
    error:
      code: 7
      message: Operation execution failed.
    metadata:
      '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.healthcare.v1.OperationMetadata
      apiMethodName: google.cloud.healthcare.v1.fhirstore.FhirStoreService.ExportResources
      counter:
        pending: '83263'
```

Am I missing some permissions somewhere?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the command you invoked? If you did not specify a service account when you ran export it should use `service-<project_number>@gcp-sa-healthcare.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. Does this have the correct permissions, like "Storage Admin"? Have you checked [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-interface) for errors?

Comment: @RiccoD I see nothing in the logs that are linked to.
The command was like:
gcloud healthcare fhir-stores export gcs <fhir store id> --project=<project> --dataset=<dataset> --location=<location> --gcs-uri=gs://<bucket>/<folder>

Comment: @RiccoD Under IAM the service account has both Logging Admin and Storage Admin.

Comment: It works fine for me using your command as well with the permissions you have mentioned on the healthcare API service account. You can file a [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub#section-2) for this to be checked.